# Consequences of BPP=BQP

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

If BPP=BQP then there is a polynomial time randomized factoring algorithm.  A lot of other quantum algorithms that appeared to have an exponential speedup have recently been dequantized. For examples, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.06151 and references therein.

What other significant practical consequences would BPP = BQP be likely to lead to?

Comment: BQP complete problem in BPP with complexity $n^{10^{10^{10^{10}}}}$ will practically get you tenure.

Comment: @VS I think you mean will definitely get you tenure in practice :)

Comment: Which exponential speedups have been dequantized?

Comment: @Mark See for example https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.06151

Comment: Simulating some of quantum mechanics.

Comment: ¿This also proposes that quantum cryptography is insecure when generated in certain contexts (ML)?

Comment: If $BQP=BPP$, then it doesn't make any sense. Why? because then Extended Church-Turing Thesis would be true or $P \neq BPP$. I believe that $BQP$ is larger class than $BPP$, i.e. $BQP \neq BPP$. Moreover, $BQP=BPP$ means quantum computation doesn't give us any powerful computation over randomized computation. And Dequantization = Derandomization.

Comment: @user777 Why doesn't it make sense?  The extended church Turing thesis might be true.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a practical algorithm is found, the applications will overwhelmingly be in quantum simulation. Basically any research in large quantum systems - chemistry, biochemistry, condensed matter, nuclear systems will be affected. We'd likely see major advances in basic biology, medicine and pharmaceuticals. Moore's law would be restored for a few years and we would finally have working fusion reactors. Physical simulation using the new algorithm might also lead to new physics.

Comment: Moore and fusion progress? Evidence?

Comment: Could you give a specific example of such a problem that is in BQP that is exponentially hard to perform classically? The more detail, the better.

Comment: The Hidden Subgroup Problems (including integer factorization, discrete logarithm, Simon's problem) are all thought to have exponential speed-ups in $NP \cap coNP$. Forrelation and Boson Sampling are believed to be outside of the polynomial hierarchy.

Comment: Efficient quantum simulation would make it easier to deal with quantum effects in chip design and to design a quantum computer. That should allow some chip speedups. Fusion should be easier because it would be much easier to predict what fusion reactors are going to do and control them.

Comment: The  Hidden Subgroup Problems  are good examples but very similar to the example given by the OP.  Can you give a mathematcal definition for a quantum chemistry simulation problem that is in BQP but not thought to be in BPP?